# In Linq to Umbraco, is there a way to find the language associated with a Node?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, umbraco

In Linq to Umbraco, is there a way to find the language associated with a Node?

for example : I have a structure where

```
content -|
         |- FR -|
                |- News
                |- Blog
                |- About

         |- EN -|
                |- News
                |- Blog
                |- About

         |- JP -|
                |- News
                |- Blog
                |- About
```

and I would like to read the root nodes (en, fr, jp) which have different names and find the language associated with it.

I'm currently refering to the language set using the hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filter it using Path property.

```
x=>x.Path.StartsWith("-1,XXX")
```